# VACUUM on Redshift (AWS) after DELETE and INSERT

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table as below (simplified example, we have over 60 fields):

```
CREATE TABLE "fact_table" (
  "pk_a" bigint                 NOT NULL ENCODE lzo,
  "pk_b" bigint                 NOT NULL ENCODE delta,
  "d_1"  bigint                 NOT NULL ENCODE runlength,
  "d_2"  bigint                 NOT NULL ENCODE lzo,
  "d_3"  character varying(255) NOT NULL ENCODE lzo,
  "f_1"  bigint                 NOT NULL ENCODE bytedict,
  "f_2"  bigint                     NULL ENCODE delta32k
)
DISTSTYLE KEY
DISTKEY ( d_1 )
SORTKEY ( pk_a, pk_b );
```

The table is distributed by a high-cardinality dimension.

The table is sorted by a pair of fields that increment in time order.

The table contains over 2 billion rows, and uses ~350GB of disk space, both "per node".

Our hourly house-keeping involves updating some recent records *(within the last 0.1% of the table, based on the sort order)* and inserting another 100k rows.

Whatever mechanism we choose, VACUUMing the table becomes overly burdensome:
- The `sort` step takes seconds
- The `merge` step takes over 6 hours

We can see from `SELECT * FROM svv_vacuum_progress;` that ***all*** 2billion rows are being merged.  Even though the first 99.9% are completely unaffected.

Our understanding was that the merge should only affect:
1. Deleted records
2. Inserted records
3. And all the records from (1) or (2) up to the end of the table

We have tried `DELETE and INSERT` rather than `UPDATE` and that DML step is now significantly quicker.  But the `VACUUM` ***still*** merges all 2billion rows.

```
DELETE FROM fact_table WHERE pk_a > X;
-- 42 seconds

INSERT INTO fact_table SELECT <blah> FROM <query> WHERE pk_a > X ORDER BY pk_a, pk_b;
-- 90 seconds

VACUUM fact_table;
-- 23645 seconds
```

In fact, the `VACUUM` merges all 2 billion records even if we just trim the last 746 rows off the end of the table.

**The Question**

Does anyone have any advice on how to avoid this immense `VACUUM` overhead, and only `MERGE` on the last 0.1% of the table?

Comment: Have you considered creating another table with just the most recent 0.1%, doing the merge, and then delete/reinsert those rows?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The delete/re-insert on the master table is still problematic.  A similar approach *(that we hope to not need)* would be to have a manual partition; `fact_35` holding the last 35 days of data (the window we expect to be volatile), `fact_hist` holding everything older (which we expect to to stable), and a view to `UNION ALL` them together.  Our hourly house-keeping would then work on a table ~30x smaller, with nightly 'shift' of 1 day's data into the master table.  *(INSERT only on `fact_hist`, never a DELETE.)*  But this has an undesirable impact on queries on the UNIONed view.

Comment: You can also consider having hourly (or daily) tables and UNION ALL them with a view or simply with your queries on the relevant time frame.

Comment: @guy - That's functionally no different from that which I have already described in my comment, and so is still liable to the same undesirable impact on query performance.

Comment: I have found this question on AWS forum. it is being investigated by someone from AWS. Note: `DELETE` in AWS does not romove rows, but marks them as deleted. This is why `VACUUM` is needed to reclaim disk space. Is there any difference by running `VACUUM` as `DELETE ONLY` or `SORT ONLY`? I could not figure out if both sort and merge staps happen for only one of these options.

Comment: @stoleg - `DELETE ONLY` only does the `MERGE` step.  *(From above, I say the the `SORT` takes seconds and the `MERGE` takes hours.)*  The confusion is that the 'deleted' records are all from the **end** of the table.  This means that I expected only the end of the table to require a `MERGE`, not the whole table, and this is supported photographically here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/vacuum-managing-volume-of-unmerged-rows.html

Comment: I 've read those articles on AWS documentation as well. You may consider Running `SORT ONLY` on regular basis and full `VACUUM` as maitenance like once a week. It is not the best solution, but there is a chance that your usage will affecteed less, than by 6 hour full `VACUUM` every day.

Comment: The only things Docs do not discuss is how is that affected by distribution key that is not same as sort key. Also encoding might change behaviuor.

Comment: I do not want to give an exact number, but you may not want to run vacuum every day unless there is an increment of more than 10% of the whole data. You do not need the whole table to be vacuumed and sorted every other time, Redshift will still be able to manage scanning unsorted blocks upto certain extent. Vacuum is ofcourse a major area where improvement is needed from Redshift and you can always chose time series tables with a union all view on top and vacuum or deep copy smaller tables much faster.

Comment: One more thing is optimizer works better with stats on sort keys after every load than vacuumed after every load in terms of resource usage.

Comment: @androboy - my previous comments point to time series tables in a UNION ALL having unacceptable performance impact.  Redshift devs are aware of this too.  Vacuuming overnight would be fine if it didn't take 16 hours.  I didn't understand your final comment.  Our current maintenance plan has VACUUM SORT ONLY after each batch of writes, and weekly VACUUM and ANALYSE.  Other than Redshift's problem with vacuuming a Delete we don't see any other resource problems.

Answer (score 1):

How often are you VACUUMing the table? How does the long duration effect you?  our load processing continues to run during VACUUM and we've never experienced any performance problems with doing that. Basically it doesn't matter how long it takes because we just keep running BAU.

I've also found that we don't need to VACUUM our big tables very often. Once a week is more than enough. Your use case may be very performance sensitive but we find the query times to be within normal variations until the table is more than, say, 90% unsorted.

If you find that there's a meaningful performance difference, have you considered using recent and history tables (inside a UNION view if needed)? That way you can VACUUM the small "recent" table quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't fix it in comments section, so posting it as answer

I think right now, if the SORT keys are same across the time series tables and you have a UNION ALL view as time series view and still performance is bad, then you may want to have a time series view structure with explicit filters as

```
create or replace view schemaname.table_name as 
select * from table_20140901 where sort_key_date = '2014-09-01' union all 
select * from table_20140902 where sort_key_date = '2014-09-02' union all .......
select * from table_20140925 where sort_key_date = '2014-09-25';
```

Also make sure to have stats collected on all these tables on sort keys after every load and try running queries against it. It should be able to push down any filter values into the view if you are using any. End of day after load, just run a VACUUM SORT ONLY or full vacuum on the current day's table which should be much faster.

Let me know if you are still facing any issues after the above test.

Comment: You're correct in that RedShift performs at it's best in this case, but it still stumbles when the filtering is done using joins, which I discussed on the phone with one of their product managers and engineers.  This is an example `SELECT dimension.label, SUM(fact.x) FROM fact, dimension WHERE fact.fk = dimension.id AND dimension.label = 'FooBar' GROUP BY dimension.label` - Even if the "time-series" tables are SORTed by the fk, and even with the explicit WHERE clauses as optimiser hints, it yields a full table scan.

Comment: Yup. We are also awaiting a fix from Redshift for pushing the filter in Join for Time series view. But how bad is it and for how many minutes is it running? If fact.fk is the dist key on fact table then it should not be that bad. In lot of cases when optimizer is going bad, we try to first create a temp table out of a subquery or part of the query with dist key and then use it in a second query with remaining parts.

Comment: I think you mean sort-key; partitioning the data in to a "time-series" by the dist-key would cause skew.  In terms of "how long"; it yields a full table scan of every underlying partitioned table.  We have in excess of 2billion rows, queries that would take seconds without manual partitioning take many minutes.  As for temp tables; most reporting suites don't let you interfere in that way; our prime example being an MDX analytical tool.